# Passing headers to bing map API

Tags: javascript, angular, bing-maps

I am making a call to Bing Maps APi like below.

```
var gcR = "https://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations?query=" + val + "&key=" + key;

return this.http.get(gcR)
    .map((res: any) => {
        return res.json();
    }).catch(
        (err: any) => {
            return err;
        }
    );
}
```

The above code is being complained **Missing HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS)** Header. What header information do we need to pass to bing maps API.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? As far as I know, no modern browser will allow you to retrieve the results from Bing from a script running on your website, it would be cross-site-scripting.

Comment: I am trying to get lattitude and longtitude from the above API call.

Comment: @Thalapathy ithu panna mudiyathu, this is violating the HTML rules

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the header of your response as required from here [HSTS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Strict-Transport-Security).

[Here](https://angular.io/guide/http#http-headers) you have the description of 'how'.